# How to read Analog Output Holding Registers on Advantech ADAM 6717 through ModBus TCP

Tags: plc, modbus-tcp

I've been exploring the [ADAM 6717](https://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile5/1-24AIQLL/ADAM-6700_Series_User_Manual_Ed.2-FINAL.pdf) from Advantech.
This is the ModBus address table for said device:
[image]

At first I wanted to modify the value of the Digital output channel 0(DO0), so, as can be seen from the picture above, such address is the 0x0017.

I succeed at this by using a ModBus tool and the following settings:
[image]

Sending either "On" or "Off", turns On and off a LED connected to that output. Everything runs smoothly according to my expectation up to this point.

The problem arises when I want to read the Analog Input channel 6 or equivalently, address 400431~40044.

Since that address lies on the **Analog Output Holding Registers** part of the address table, I though that the following settings would accomplish the job:

[image]

However, as can be seen above, the reading shows 0.0 when there is actually 6V connected to that input (a potentiometer)

It is worth mentioning that I've made sure to enable the AI6 channel as well as setting it to Voltage mode instead of current. Also, the web utility for the device shows the AI6 reading correctly as I change the potentiometer's resistance value.

So the problem doesn't lie in the connection from the potentiometer to the AI6 but somewhere else.

Out of nothing and leaving aside what I think I know on this topic, I though of changing the function from 0x03 to 0x04

[image]

However, the response is exactly the same.

It bugs me that I can read and write values to the output coils but not the Analog output holding registers.

Is there any configuration that I might be missing over here?

Thanks in advance.

Device settings:
IP address: 10.0.0.1
Port in which the ModBus service is running: 5020

Comment: Hello Juan David. Have you tried clicking those byte swap and word swap checkboxes? That might help depending on your device.

Comment: If that's not helping you can try with a different tool, for instance, [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)

Comment: try [modpoll](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll) if you prefer python